# Photoshop feathers selections even though I turned it off

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, selections, anti-aliasing

This is what happens when I try to fill the selection with black.

[image]

It's super janky! What I want is to turn off all feathering to have a perfect crisp edge, but I can't figure out how to do that. Sorry for German interface, I would set it to English if I could. The option bar at the top for the selection tool says "Weiche Kante: 0px", which means feathering I think. "Glätten" means "anti-aliasing" and it's grayed out.
The paint bucket tool also doesn't seem to have any helpful options.

I'm using CS6 btw.

Edit: I think I know what's going on. The selection is essentially an alpha mask and isn't binary. The outline is just trying to give me an idea what the mask really looks like. It would be nice if there were just a button to make the selection binary without jumping through hoops.

Comment: I've been trying to replicate this behavior and I can't.  I have no clue what is causing that behavior, because my edges always come out crisp.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, but with the quick selection tool.  What fixed it for me was after every time I made a selection, I had to go into the "Refine Edge..." menu, which for you is called "Kante Verbessern...", here:
[image]

And make sure the contrast slider, under "Adjust Edge", was set all the way to 100%, here:
[image]

Then I hit OK, which refined the edge of my current selection, so I was then able fill it in with sharp, pixel-perfect edges! I hope this fixes your issue like it did mine!

Answer (score 0):

I think the resolution of the image is low enough that you are seeing a jagged edge, with anti-aliasing, not feathering. Feathering would produce a longer transition between dark and white or transparent. The individual pixels are visible and there appears to be only one "row" with some grays. I could be wrong of course, but if you set feathering to 0, then that is the way to obtain a crisp edge.