# photoshop selection is fuzzy

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I found a duplicate post [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76610/photoshop-feathers-selections-even-though-i-turned-it-off) but with no answers. I looked at [this guide from adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/smoothing-selection-edges-anti-aliasing.html) on how to feather edges hoping I'd find an answer but my Feather: option is already at 0 px. I have never had this issue before in photoshop or any other editor, but I also haven't touched any settings since the last time I used it so I have no clue what on to do. The photo, as you can clearly see, is pretty big but even so it shouldn't be coming out feathered. I even went to **select -> modify -> feather** and set the value to 0.1px but that didn't help.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Comment: You are zoomed in 400+% on what appears to be a very small, low resolution, image. Garbage in <> Garbage out.

Comment: okay again, the image is big enough. It's 3840x2160. And also again, that shouldn't feather the edges. I opened it up in paint.net and it just cut out the pixels. In the cut command, pdn cut out the pixels. Mind blown. I just want photoshop to be able to cut out the pixels not add anti-aliasing and feathering and whatever. Further, clearly if I'm over 400% zoom and the photo still has good pixel definition the "grabage in" is not garbage.

Comment: How are you making the initial selection? The gif tells us nothing useful. [btw, select -> modify -> feather is always going to **add** feathering, not reduce any existing.]

Comment: Uncheck the anti-alias option in the tool options along the top. Make your selection, then delete/cut the selection.

Comment: Sorry for leaving that in there, I used the quick selection tool which doesn't even have that option. I was seeing if toggling it did anything and it doesn't. (Also, hardness is at 100% and if it means anything spacing is at 1%)

Comment: Then use "Select and Mask" after using Quick Select, to increase the contrast of the selection. It will not be perfect, because that tool is supposed to make anti-aliased selections. Perhaps better to use a different method of selecting, such as using the lasso, or polygon select if you don't want anti-aliasing.

Comment: Honestly I'm just gonna use a different program if that's how it's designed to work and there's no option to toggle it. There's like 500 different menus in Photoshop, it should be able to cut without anti-aliasing if I want it to.

Comment: I can see in your video that you have checked "Anti-alias" (top left corner). Uncheck that and see if it works the way you want.

Comment: I'm sure you thought that was a great comment but it was already discussed a few comments up and it's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Marquee tools* and the *Lasso tools* (as you are showing in your video) can be either aliased or anti-aliased.

*Quick Selection Tool* doesn't have an option to turn anti-aliasing off.

A quick workaround could be this:

- Make your selection with *Quick Selection Tool* (or any other way).
- Hit <kbd>Q</kbd> to enter *Quick Mask Mode*.
- Apply *Image > Adjustments > Threshold* and just keep the *Threshold Level* at *128*.
- Hit <kbd>Q</kbd> again to leave *Quick Mask Mode*.

Now your selection is 1-bit with no anti-aliasing.

Comment: Yeah that seems like way too much work just to select something considering how often I used that tool in that project. I just went with a different program. Still a valid answer though.

Comment: Ok. But why can't you just use Photoshop's Lasso Tool with anti-aliasing turned off? Which program did you switch to?

Comment: I needed something with edge detection, so I used gimp. Usually I use pdn when photoshop is being annoying, but I don't think I have an edge detection plugin. The best part, it has anti-aliasing and feathering options should I decide to use them but doesn't force me to. Amazing what free stuff can do.